# Adding Node.Js to C++

Tags: c++, node.js

I am developing an autonomous TCP server based data acquisition service which collects data form our embedded hardware and pushes it forward over necessary interface. Performance, scalability and reliability is important as it is autonomous and field configurable system.

I am developing the service primarily C++ (database operation, encryption, decryption and control).
I would like to develop the TCP Server in Node.Js because of simplicity in scalability compared to C++.
Is their a way to tightly integrate this Node.Js TCP server in my C++ application something like Node.Js C++ Addons but where Node.Js code can be imported in C++ and not the other way around.

I am attempting to get the received data driectly from the TCP server in Node.Js into C++ native (byte array, etc.) or complex variable (like string, stringbuffer object etc.) for further processing.

Comment: How exactly do you expect this to integrate, is a single thread OK or do you need the C++ to be in background worker threads of some sort? If the former is OK, you could write your C++ as a native C module, import it and call the functions in response to TCP reads etc, or must Node.JS be *hosted* by C++ or some other integration?

Comment: I was thinking on the line that my Win64 C++ service should host the Node.Js TCP Server. As and when the data is received, it will be copied in C++ variable in my main thread for further processing and at the same time C++ should be able to call data send function written in node.js as required. Single Threaded application will be okay.

Comment: Hosting node is a bit of a pain, you can find resources online but most information to make things easier are in the module world and node likes to have its own event loop that owns the thread. A module is generally easier unless you are writing a plugin or such and don't control the process anyway. Seems people like to use Lua, Python, etc. rather than Node, I have seen V8 itself used directly a couple of times.

Comment: Have you considered a socket connection between your C++ code and the Node server? Depending on the details, either the C++ code calls Node when it wants more data, or Node pushes the data it has collected to a listener in C++.

Comment: @TripeHound, The service has to be self contained and self installed (with standard installer) with minimal outside configuration but I will definitely look into this approach but am little hesitant as Node server requires explicit configuration. I will be looking for IPC mechanism.

Comment: @FireLancer, I am also looking into V8 and libuv. Was hoping for some simpler alternative. If all out fails I will use either Boost.Asio or libuv.

Comment: "The service has to be self contained and self installed (with standard installer) with minimal " any reason not to make node essentially *the service* and put the C into a module? You could maybe write a very thin wrapper if need be but if you control the structure of the overall service so that the "core" can be in JS that would be simplest I think. Even if your C module then spawns its own threads node knows nothing about to do other work.